# Counting elements in array recursively - big arrays

Tags: java

I am learning recursion and I am supposed to create a recursive method to count number of apperances of a specific number in an array, e.g.; {1,2,3,4,4,5} for number 4 should return 2. I know that recursion is not the ideal problem to solve this issue and I know that using endIndex is not ideal either, but that's just a textbook problem I can't seem to solve.

My method is not working well, since I always run out of heap when running through big arrays. How would I optimize such code? Thanks!

```
 public static int countNumber(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex, int 
   number) {
    int result = 0;
    if (startIndex==endIndex) {
        return result;
    }
    if (array[startIndex] == number ) {
        result++;
    }
    result = result + countNumber(array,startIndex+1,endIndex,number);
    return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you run out of *heap*, not out of *stack*? Because running out of stack on a big array is something quite expected here. The depth of the recursion is always limited by the stack size.

You could split the array into two parts on each iteration and run the method recursively on both parts. That way, for n elements of the input array, the depth of recursion would be log2(n) instead of n. Something along the following lines:

```java
if (startIndex == endIndex) {
    if (array[startIndex] == number) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
return countNumber(array, startIndex, (startIndex + endIndex) / 2, number)
        + countNumber(array, (startIndex + endIndex) / 2 + 1, endIndex, number);
```

Of course, you could also just increase stack size (e.g. with -Xss10m parameter), or simply limit the size of your input array.

Comment: Hey, your code throws array index out of bounds exception.

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixed.